# Can an attacker bypass this DOM XSS filter?

Tags: xss

I'm not asking to break someone's security, but can an attacker bypass this filter?

What should I add to secure it more or it is enough?

```
var target = window.location.hash.replace(/[^\w-_]/g, '');
$('#sel-' + target).addClass('pressed');
```

Comment: Doesn't jQuery only treat the string passed to it as a CSS selector if it doesn't start with '<'? The most you can do here then is tweak the CSS selector.

Comment: How would you exploit this if there wan't a filter? Which code do you want to bypass the filter?

Comment: @AgentME so you think that an attacker can attack my site through css injection, am i right?

Comment: @Sjoerd If you're asking before I added these filters, I could exploit my site via many payloads.

Comment: What kind of attacks worked before you added the filter? I can't see how this could be exploitable in any way besides allowing a child of #sel-... to have the pressed class added to it.

Comment: @AgentME It was vulnerable to dom based cross site scripting, a friend of mine told me that it's still vulnerable, that an attacker can bypass the filter. Do you have any suggestion, so I can secure it more?

Comment: What's an example input that it used to be vulnerable to? I'm still unclear what kind of exploit could target this without the filter, so I can't say what benefit the filter is.

Comment: @AgentME I used this payload #"><img src=x onerror=prompt('XSS');>

Comment: I can't get that attack to work. I made https://jsbin.com/husirosawu/2/edit?html,js,console,output which prompts for the hash value once you hit "Run with JS" at the top right. Entering in that value doesn't break anything.

Comment: @AgentME It seems now safe because all XSS introducing characters are filtered out prior to being added to the DOM. Thanks again

Comment: @BiniShala My example there didn't have any filtering done.

Comment: @AgentME Yeah, I saw it but maybe something was changed then I updated my site. But now with the filter it seems safe to me.